# Find equation from differential equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

The balloon being inflated radius changes at a constant rate.
If initially its radius is $3$ units and after $3$ seconds it is $6$ units. Find the radius of the balloon after $t$ seconds.
The answer is in the terms of $t$. 
Please suggest how to proceed ?

Comment: What changes at a constant rate?

Answer (score 2):

Notice, let $r$ be the radius at any time $t$ then its volume is given as $$V=\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3$$ $$\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}$$
But the balloon is inflated at constant rate say $k$ then rate of change of volume $\frac{dV}{dt}=k$ hence we get
$$4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}=k$$ $$r^2\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{k}{4\pi}$$
$$\int r^2dr=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int dt$$ $$\frac{r^3}{3}=\frac{k}{4\pi}t+C$$
Now, we have the following conditions

1. initially at time $t=0$, radius $r=3$  then 
   $$\frac{(3)^3}{3}=\frac{k}{4\pi}(0)+C\implies C=9$$
2. at time $t=3\ sec$, radius $r=6$ then 
   $$\frac{(6)^3}{3}=\frac{k}{4\pi}(3)+9\implies k=84\pi$$
   Hence, we get $$\frac{r^3}{3}=\frac{84\pi}{4\pi}t+9$$
   $$\frac{r^3}{3}=21t+9$$$$\implies \color{red}{r^3=63t+27}$$